# Prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 5}\left(4x^2-7\right)=93$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

So I first need to determine the limit and then prove it:

> $\lim \limits_{x \to 5}\left(4x^2-7\right)$

So $L=93$

And thus $\left|f(x)-L\right|=\epsilon$ and $\left|x-c\right|=\delta$

Plugging in the values...

$\left|\left(4x^2-7\right)-93\right| \lt \epsilon$, which when factored gives $4(x+5)\left|x-5\right|\lt \epsilon$

So does this mean:

$\left|x-5\right|\lt 4(x+5)\delta$

Comment: Since you are interested in the behavior as $x\to 5$, why don't you try assuming that $x$ is relatively near $5$, say $x\le 6$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get rid of $x+5$, as it is a function of $x$.
In order to do this, we fix an arbitrary  delta say 1 and take minimum from 1 and a new delta which will be obtained.
More precisley  we already know that $|x-5|<\delta$.
Now put $\delta=1$ and $9<x+5<11$ is obtained.
Let us go back to our limit.
One may see that $4(x+5)(x-5)<4(x-5)\times 11=44(x-5)<44\delta$ and so we have to have $\delta<\frac{1}{44}\epsilon$.
Hence we can conclude that $\delta\leq min\{1,\frac{1}{44}\epsilon\}$

Comment: Could I have literally chosen any $\delta$?

Comment: yep, it does not make any difference, Actually our objective is removing x+5 in the above, so pick up arbitrary $\delta$ and go further.

Comment: Sorry last question, when $\delta=1$ I get $x=4$ and $x=6$.  What am I missing in my math?

Comment: after taking 1 as $\delta$, you will  get x between 4 and 6. Now we are intersted in $x+5$ and so we get $9<x<11$

Comment: Ahhh ok got it.

Comment: it is fun if you look at the limit of x^3 whenever x goes to 2.

Comment: What does the $\text{min}\{\}$ mean?

Comment: $\min(a,b)$ is the value of the smallest number, i.e: it is $a$ if $a < b$ and it is $b$ if $a>b$.

Answer (score 1):

the next step.

Find $\delta$ such that when $|x-5|<\delta, |4(x + 5)(x-5)| < \epsilon$

let $\delta = \min (1, \frac {\epsilon}{44})$

Why 44?

Suppose $x-5 = \delta, |4(x + 5)(x-5)| = \delta \le 1 \implies |4(\delta + 10) \delta| = 4 \delta^2 + 40 \delta$

If $\delta \le 1$ then  $|4(x + 5)(x-5)| < 44 \delta$

$\delta = \min (1, \frac {\epsilon}{44}) \implies |4(x + 5)(x-5)| < \epsilon.$